# Delaying browser Ajax output (LongPolling)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, long-polling

I'm trying to complete a connection using Long Polling, where the browser sends a request to the server and to be awaiting a response. To prevent this door is infinitely open, I created a routine that every 10 seconds the server sends an empty response to the browser, stating that there was nothing yet.

It's all working perfectly, had no problems related to that.

My problem is that when the user clicks on a link on the page, the browser waits for the answer call for power upgrade, or can take up to 10-sec. This makes it appear that the tool is slow.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

1. Image:

   [image: img1]
2. Image:

   [image: img2]

Follows the JavaScript function used to make the call:

```
function loadJSON() {

    if(libera) {

        var data_file = http + "bibliotecas/longpolling/notificacoes.php";

        var data = {};
            data.n = long_n;
            data.u = userchat;
            data.m = msgchat;
            data.c = chatUsuario;

        http_request.onreadystatechange  = function() {

            if(http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200) {

                try {
                    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);
                    var qtd = jsonObj.funcao.length;
                    if(qtd > 0) {
                        var funcao = "";
                        for(var key in jsonObj.funcao) {
                            funcao = jsonObj.funcao[key];
                            MontarFuncao(eval(funcao),jsonObj.metodo[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (e) {
                    //alert('Erro - '+ http_request.responseText);
                }

                loadJSON();
            }
        }

        var string = JSON.stringify(data);

        http_request.open("POST", data_file, true);
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", string.length);
        http_request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        http_request.send(string);  

        return;
    }
}
```

Follows the PHP function responsible for staying open expecting some changes in the database:

```
ob_start();
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents(`php://input`));

while($x < 5) {

    if(time() >= (15 + $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) || connection_aborted()) {
        echo str_pad(NULL,1);
        die(json_encode(array()));
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        break;
    }

    //Query DB

    if(count($retorno) > 0) {
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        echo json_encode($retorno);
        exit;           
    }
    else {
        flush();
        sleep(2);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use server sent events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: Sorry, did not understand the reason for the question. What will influence the Sessions? The real problem is that the server waits for 10sec. exchange for each page.

Comment: If you have sessions open on long poll thread, this will lock the session file and any parallel requests using session array must wait for polling thread to close session before the other requests can advance

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: Closing your session when you don't need to write to it.  `session_write_close()`

Comment: FoX, did not work =/, the server still expect loop to update the page